# Retrieving data from JSON in python, and if object name matches, then store the key of that object

Tags: python, json, rest

I am making REST calls on a server. The first REST call gets all the projects and from that I store the project's IDs in an array. 
Below is the JSON. 
For e.g. it would return something like this:

```
[
    {
        "expand": "description,lead,url,projectKeys",
        "self": "http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/project/10101",
        "id": "10101",
        "key": "GR1",
        "name": "Group1Project",
        "avatarUrls": {
            "48x48": "http://localhost:8080/secure/projectavatar?avatarId=10324",
            "24x24": "http://localhost:8080/secure/projectavatar?size=small&avatarId=10324",
            "16x16": "http://localhost:8080/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10324",
            "32x32": "http://localhost:8080/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&avatarId=10324"
        },
        "projectTypeKey": "software"
    }
]
```

Then I'm looping through that array and making another REST call for each project id(10101).
This gives me groups/users against that project. 
For example:

```
{
    "self": "http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/project/10000/role/10100",
    "name": "Developers",
    "id": 10100,
    "actors": [
        {
            "id": 10207,
            "displayName": "group2",
            "type": "atlassian-group-role-actor",
            "name": "group2",
            "avatarUrl": "http://localhost:8080/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10123"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get all the project IDs where `name == group2`.

Following is my Python code for all of this but it's not working.

```
import requests

ids = []

response = requests.get('http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/project',
                        auth=('*', '*'))
data = response.json()

for line in data:
    ids.append(line["id"])

print(ids)  


# Check if group exists in Project roles.
# If it does, then save the project name in the list of arrays.

projectNames = []

for id in ids:
    url = 'http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/project/'+id+'/role/10100'
    response = requests.get(url,
                            auth = ('*', '*'))

    data = response.json()

    if data.displayName == 'group2':
        projectNames.append(["id"])
```

Could you please help me out how to do this? 
Thank you.

Comment: In second json you want to compare with its 'name' or with every actor?

Comment: I want to compare with every actor who has a  "displayName": "group2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tayyab,
You need to do this. It will work.

```
for actor in data['actors']:
    if actor['displayName']=='group2':
        projectNames.append(id)
```

Comment: You should change the name of your variable projectName since you are storing ids in it. Change it to projectIds may be.

Comment: Bohdan we are getting id from the block above  "for id in ids:".

Answer (score 1):

```
projectNames = []

for id in ids:
    url = 'http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/project/'+id+'/role/10100'
    response = requests.get(url,
                        auth = ('*', '*'))

    data = response.json()
    for actor in data["actors"]:
        if actor["displayName"] and actor["displayName"] == "group2":
            projectNames.append(actor["id"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
projectNames = set()
for id in ids:
    url = 'http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/project/'+id+'/role/10100'
    response = requests.get(url,
                            auth = ('*', '*'))
    data = response.json()

    group2_actors = [actor['id'] for actor in data['actors']
                     if actor['displayName'] == 'group2']
    if len(group2_actors) > 0:
        projectNames.update(group2_actors)
```

`projectNames` is a set of unique actor ids with `displayName` == `group2`.

Answer (score -1):

```
some_json = {}
result = [actor['id'] for actor in some_json['actors'] if actor['name']=='group2']
```

so `result` for that second json will be `[10207]`